# File input of avformat_open_input in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use function `avformat_open_input` in *FFmpeg* to open the file which contains Chinese word.

For example:

```
char* file="C:/測試/baby.mp4";

avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, file, NULL, NULL);
```

But, it seems to be failed.

My question is how do I pass the file path which contains Chinese (or other languages except for English) ?

Comment: `'測試'` cannot be represented as a `char`. Sorry I don't know if ffmpeg supports unicode filenames.

Comment: There is a patch to handle utf8 filenames, google for "ffmpeg winutf8_open"